# MVC when developing in objective-C without using the Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller, design-patterns

What is the correct way of implementing true MVC in Objective-C (Cocoa/iPhone) when the view is NOT created with Interface Builder?

How do I best structure the code and tie the different components of the MVC pattern together when I'm not using the Interface Builder in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you are trying to create a view without any help from a nib file, you will have to implement that view's controller's *loadView* method.

So my answer is, any stuff related to V goes to the *loadView* method in your controller's implementation, any other logic stuff related to C goes to the rest part of your controller's implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I want to separate the View furthermore into a separate class instead of creating all UI components in a method, would you recommend doing that in a separate class that derives from UIView ?

Comment: @Emmanuel: I understand your concern about keeping separated modules as separated as possible. However, as a general practice, if we decide to programmatically construct a subclass of UIView we usually do it in the controller that *controls* it. It does reduce the reusability of our codes to some extent. But it makes the following wiring-outlets work less time-consuming and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a matter of taste : some absolutely think that to one viewController you can have one and only one view so the only manner is to subclass UIView for every view. I totally accept that a viewController manages multiple sub view constituting a screen and I only subclass UIView where it make sense in term of reusability.  In fact, I also accept that a viewController use multiple viewControllers to manage different isolated part of the view as does the UINavigationContoller for example.

Answer (score -2):

Usually you create a subclass of the element you want to display. For instance a UITableView which you set in the init method. This way, you're ViewController just dequeues an instance of it